# virtualbox boot from partition - incompatible license error

Tags: linux, virtualbox, partitioning, permissions

I would like to use a partition (contianing Windows 10 x64) in virtualbox.

**What I have done:**

1. (Obviously) Installed vitualbox
2. Created a vmdk from the partition with:

**Creating vmdk from /dev/sda1**

```
sudo VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename win_hdd_raw.vmdk -rawdisk /dev/sda -partitions 1
```

3. setting permissions and ownership on 2 files created:

**before permissions**

```
cx@cx-W55xEU:~$ ll win_hdd_raw*
-rw------- 1 root root 161280 Nov 21 10:59 win_hdd_raw-pt.vmdk
-rw------- 1 root root    931 Nov 21 10:59 win_hdd_raw.vmdk
cx@cx-W55xEU:~$ sudo chmod 666 win_hdd_raw*
```

**after permissions**

```
cx@cx-W55xEU:~$ ll win_hdd_raw*
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 161280 Nov 21 10:59 win_hdd_raw-pt.vmdk
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root    931 Nov 21 10:59 win_hdd_raw.vmdk
```

**setting ownership**

```
cx@cx-W55xEU:~$ sudo chown cx:cx win_hdd_raw*
cx@cx-W55xEU:~$ ll win_hdd_raw*
-rw------- 1 cx cx 161280 Nov 21 10:59 win_hdd_raw-pt.vmdk
-rw------- 1 cx cx    931 Nov 21 10:59 win_hdd_raw.vmdk
```

4. Adding current user to disk group

**Add user to disk**

```
sudo usermod -a -G disk cx
```

**side note:**

Opening virtualbox as `cx` or normal user and attempting to add the vmdk, results in:

```
Permission problem accessing the file for the medium '/home/cx/win_hdd_raw.vmdk' (VERR_ACCESS_DENIED).

Result Code: VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80BB0004)

Component: Medium
```

Thus, opening virtual box as root allows me to import/open the vmdk as expected.

**My problem:**

While virtual box is open as root, starting up the VM, I get an error:

```
(brief flashing Unknown device)

incompatible license
Aported. Press any key to exit.FATAL: INT18: BOOT FAILURE
```

Setting the motherboard option for Enable EFI to checked, results in the following:
[image: efi_enabled_error]

[Log File](http://pastebin.com/qAUFa1Rn)

any advice?

Comment: where did you get your version of VirtualBox?  There are two copies Oracle's [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/virtualbox/downloads/index.html) licensed one and the opensource one (http://virtualbox.org).  The former requires a license to run but I'm not sure what if any verification it does to ensure you have a license.

Comment: Actually I'm mistaken, Oracle's release is identical to their opensource release.  It looks like Oracle is only licensing OEM and the extension packs.  Neither of those two components should cause the issues you're seeing

Comment: Is there any reason you're not directly creating the `.vmdk` file using the `cx` user? Could it be possible that you already have Windows installed on that partition? If so what Edition is it?

Comment: @Seth Hi, if you reread the question, the first sentence, you should see that Windows is already installed on the partition of which I have created the vmdk from, and from that you will also see that it is Windows 10 64bit. To answer your question regarding "directly creating the vmdk." This is not allowed as I did not have the appropriate permissions, i.e. I was not part of the disk group, I only added it later after creating the vmdk, adding myself the the group will allow me to create a vmdk from my current user : `cx` as I have access to the /dev/ block (If I am not mistaken)

Comment: Yes, I could've read that it's already installed but it's still missing the Edition. Home, Pro, Enterprise, Education etc. can have some different limitations on how they can be used in a virtualized environment. As far as I know it's been simplified but it might have something to do with that. If you did install that Windows the normal way (not using VBox) you're essentially moving an installed OS to a new computer without reinstalling it. In addition you're not using a partition for the VMDK but instead the whole disk. Would it happen to be your system disk? Seeing some relations to GRUB.

Comment: @Seth my apologies, I misunderstood what you meant with Edition. This is, I believe Windows  10 x64 Pro (pre-release betaR2 - the Insider preview builds). Windows has been installed the normal way, which has been placed onto partition `sda1`. Something of note is when creating the vmdk, I specified `-partitions 1` which refers to the first partition of the `sda` device. But when loading the vmdk, I noticed that my total harddrive space which is 465Gb was listed, and not the +/-260gb which should be listed. Do you think it is not using the partition but the entire disk?

Comment: Good catch on your part. If (on Windows) I run `VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk` I get a help text that reads: `On Linux or FreeBSD host the parameter -relative causes a VMDK file to be created which refers to individual partitions instead to the entire disk.` So yes, it's likely it's referring to the entire disk right now and if you're dual booting it's possible its trying to load GRUB which fails. There are quite a few hits for GRUB+"`incompatible license`".

Comment: @Seth thank you for the clarity, I shall attempt it later today, if this is successful, I shall never boot into Windows directly :p Linux > Windows (had to put it out there) :p